# Problem Executing NirSoft SearchMyFiles.exe from Powershell

Tags: powershell

I know this is a problem in how I'm passing the arguments but I can't figure it out as it looks like I've successfully escaped the characters that might cause a problem.

```
PS> $ExecutionPath = "G:\BEKDocs\NonInstPrograms\NirSoftx64"
$PgmName       = "Searchmyfiles.exe"
$RunCmd        = Join-Path -Path "$ExecutionPath" -ChildPath "$PgmName"
$MyArgs        = " `/config `"G:\BEKDocs\TestSMF.cfg`" `/StartSearch `/ExplorerCopy `/stext `"G:\BEKDocs\TestSMF.txt`""
$runcmd        += $MyArgs
& $Runcmd

---Results: No file Created no Error messages displayed---

--- Show the Created Command ---

PS> $RunCmd
G:\BEKDocs\NonInstPrograms\NirSoftx64\Searchmyfiles.exe /config "G:\BEKDocs\TestSMF.cfg" /StartSearch /ExplorerCopy /stex
t "G:\BEKDocs\TestSMF.txt"

--- Try to Execute the command from History ---

PS> G:\BEKDocs\NonInstPrograms\NirSoftx64\Searchmyfiles.exe /config "G:\BEKDocs\TestSMF.cfg" /StartSearch /ExplorerCopy /stex
t "G:\BEKDocs\TestSMF.txt"

--- Result: No file created no Error messages displayed. ---

--- Type the command by hand ---

PS> G:\BEKDocs\NonInstPrograms\NirSoftx64\searchmyfiles.exe /config "G:\BEKDocs\TestSMF.cfg" /StartSearch /ExplorerCopy /stext "G:\BEKDocs\TestSMF.txt"

--- Result: File CREATED as expected ---
PS>
```

I'm at a loss!

Comment: Why are we seeing a linebreak between `/stex` and `t "G:\BEKDocs\TestSMF.txt"` ?

Comment: Theo, I don't know. I tried retyping that section of the script and no changes in the run sequence shown above. It's just where PS wrapped the line.

Comment: Have you tried to EchoArgs in place of SearchMyFiles.exe?  Great tool for seeing what parameters are being passed to an exe.  Can download from here: https://ss64.com/ps/call.html

Comment: Ah, thanks, it just looked as if there was a ````n```` in there we couldn't see

Comment: Daren, I gave it a try and it doesn't execute just like SearchMyFiles unless I print the variable $RunCmd, copy it and then paste it back into the command window. When it does run only shows 3 arguments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think every time I tried to include both the EXE name and the parameters in the same string, [The call operator (&)](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html) fails.  With that in mind, try something where $Runcmd is pointing only to the EXE and nothing else.  This also makes testing easy by temporarily placing the path to [EchoArgs](https://ss64.com/ps/call.html) in $Runcmd to view the actual parameters the EXE will be receiving.

This code example uses the [Stop-parsing token (--%)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters#stop-parsing-token---) and environmental variables to build the parameters passed to the EXE in $Runcmd.

```
$ExecutionPath = "G:\BEKDocs\NonInstPrograms\NirSoftx64"
$PgmName       = "Searchmyfiles.exe"
$RunCmd        = Join-Path -Path "$ExecutionPath" -ChildPath "$PgmName"
$Env:Config = '"G:\BEKDocs\TestSMF.cfg"'
$Env:SText = '"G:\BEKDocs\TestSMF.txt"'
& $Runcmd --% /config %Config% /StartSearch /ExplorerCopy /stext %SText%
```

Comment: Darin, EXCELLENT! Now if someone could just explain why you have to work-around the may pole to get this to work, especially when the value in original code's $RunCmd when displayed, copied and pasted works?

Comment: @RetiredGeek, I agree.  It seems like you have really go out of your way to do something that should be really simple.

Answer (score 1):

In testing it appears that it is treating `$Runcmd` — both executable path and parameters — as one complete executable path to execute.  I believe this is explained by the following section of [`about_Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-)...

> The call operator does not parse strings. This means that you cannot use command parameters within a string when you use the call operator.
>
> ```powershell
> PS> $c = "Get-Service -Name Spooler"
> PS> $c
> Get-Service -Name Spooler
> PS> & $c
> & : The term 'Get-Service -Name Spooler' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
> ```

Instead, pass the executable path and parameters to the call operator separately...

```powershell
$ExecutionPath = "G:\BEKDocs\NonInstPrograms\NirSoftx64"
$PgmName       = "Searchmyfiles.exe"
$RunPath       = Join-Path -Path "$ExecutionPath" -ChildPath "$PgmName"
$MyArgs        = @(
    '/config',       '"G:\BEKDocs\TestSMF.cfg"',
    '/StartSearch',
    '/ExplorerCopy',
    '/stext',        '"G:\BEKDocs\TestSMF.txt"'
)

& $RunPath $MyArgs
```

You'll notice that `$MyArgs` is now an array and not a `[String]`.  It seems that if `$MyArgs` is a `[String]` or a single-element array it gets passed to the executable as *one parameter* surrounded by double quotes.  Stored as above each array element gets passed as a parameter with no additional quoting.  If you still want to define `$MyArgs` using one line of text you could do so like this...

```powershell
$MyArgsText    = '/config "G:\BEKDocs\TestSMF.cfg" /StartSearch /ExplorerCopy /stext "G:\BEKDocs\TestSMF.txt"'
# NOTE: This only works because the path parameters contain no spaces
$MyArgs        = $MyArgsText -split ' '
```

All of the above is why, for anything but ad hoc commands, I would prefer the self-documenting, obvious-as-to-which-string-is-treated-as-which nature of a [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) call with explicitly-named parameters over the call operator.  Given...

```powershell
$ExecutionPath = "G:\BEKDocs\NonInstPrograms\NirSoftx64"
$PgmName       = "Searchmyfiles.exe"
$RunPath       = Join-Path -Path "$ExecutionPath" -ChildPath "$PgmName"
$MyArgsText    = '/config "G:\BEKDocs\TestSMF.cfg" /StartSearch /ExplorerCopy /stext "G:\BEKDocs\TestSMF.txt"'
```

...then both this...

```powershell
Start-Process -FilePath $RunPath -ArgumentList $MyArgsText
```

...and this...

```powershell
# NOTE: This only works because the path parameters contain no spaces
$MyArgs        = $MyArgsText -split ' '

Start-Process -FilePath $RunPath -ArgumentList $MyArgs
```

...execute `$RunPath` with the same parameters.

Comment: Lance, Thanks that helps explain things somewhat. I guess this all comes down to how the language developers decide things should be handled. Even if not understandable to us mere mortals...